# Give this set $X=\{1,2,3\}$, there are 4 possible $\sigma$-algebra and 4 possible measurable spaces in total, is my understanding right?

Tags: measure-theory

Wiki gives this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space) to illustrate Measurable space.

> Look at the set
>
> ${\displaystyle X=\{1,2,3\}.}$
>
> One possible $\sigma$-Algebra would be
>
> ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {A}}_{1}=\{X,\emptyset \}.}$
>
> Then ${\displaystyle (X,{\mathcal {A}}_{1})}$ is a measurable space.
>
> Another possible $\sigma$-algebra would be the power set on X:
>
> ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {A}}_{2}={\mathcal {P}}(X).}$
>
> With this, a second measurable space on the set X is given by ${\displaystyle (X,{\mathcal {A}}_{2})}$

besides above, is following the rest of possible $\sigma$-algebra on X?

${\mathcal {A}}_{3}=\{X, \emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3\}\}$

${\mathcal {A}}_{4}=\{X, \emptyset, \{1,3\}, \{2\}\}$

So, the rest of the possible measurable spaces on the set X are $(X,{\mathcal {A}}_{3})$ and $(X,{\mathcal {A}}_{4})$.

Give this set $X=\{1,2,3\}$, there are 4 possible $\sigma$-algebra and 4 possible measurable spaces in total, no more other else, is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing ${\mathcal {A}}_{5}=\{X, \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The count of sigma-algebras of $\{1,2,3\}$ equals the count of its partitions.

The **five** partitions of $\{1,2,3\}$ are

- $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$
- $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$
- $\{\{2\},\{1,3\}\}$
- $\{\{3\},\{1,2\}\}$
- $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$

The respective sigma-algebra for a partition is its completion under countable unions and (relative) complementation.